# Issue extending a controller that extends another controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In my SAPUI5 application I have a controller (Produzione-Stato) that extend another controller (ExcelGenerator). In the Component.js file I have added the following property:

```
customizing: {
       "sap.ui.controllerExtensions": {
            "cabot.ui.wt.controller.Produzione-Stato": {
                controllerName: "cabot.ui.wt.controller.ExcelGenerator",
                },
       }
}
```

The application works fine at this stage. However I would like the ExcelGenerator controller to extend another controller (say C2ExcelGenerator). I have tried to modify the Component.js file by adding the following:

```
customizing: {
       "sap.ui.controllerExtensions": {
            "cabot.ui.wt.controller.Produzione-Stato": {
                controllerName: "cabot.ui.wt.controller.ExcelGenerator",
                },
            "cabot.ui.wt.controller.ExcelGenerator": {
                 controllerName: "cabot.ui.wt.controller.C2ExcelGenerator",
                },
       }
}
```

This however throws exceptions errors. What is the correct approach to extend controllers on a multilevel stage or to have a controller that extend more than one controller?

Comment: Did you try using simple extend method of any controller? https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller

Answer (score 2):

Using *typed controllers* with the [`extend`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller/methods/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend) syntax the questioned scenario would look like:

`Produzione-Stato.controller.js`:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
    return Controller.extend("cabot.ui.wt.controller.Produzione-Stato", {
        onInit: function() {}
        ...
    });
});
```

`ExcelGenerator.controller.js`:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "cabot/ui/wt/controller/Produzione-Stato"
], function(PSController) {
    return PSController.extend("cabot.ui.wt.controller.ExcelGenerator", {
        onInit: function() {
            PSController.prototype.onInit.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        ...
    });
});
```

`C2ExcelGenerator.controller.js`:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "cabot/ui/wt/controller/ExcelGenerator"
], function(EGController) {
    return EGController.extend("cabot.ui.wt.controller.C2ExcelGenerator", {
        onInit: function() {
            EGController.prototype.onInit.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        ...
    });
});
```

> The chaining of the lifecycle methods is not done automatically. You
>   can control on your own, if or when to call the parent lifecycle
>   methods. In addition, you can always access the methods defined in the
>   original controller.

About typed controller extension in [Controller Replacement](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/b0b14bf4dcdb476fb0d63877c1beff7c)